# errors : {"parse":true"} prevent enable submit button in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Hi Dear All AngularJs lovers,

i am fetching a  angularjs problem in from validation.
i create directive for pattern validation, length validation and also check data are exits in database

in submit button i use **ng-disable='frm.$invalid'** but though my all input field are valid, my submit button shows still disable , because i get   errors : {"parse":true"}

if it shows like that **errors : {" "}** then my submit button enable 
how can i solved it.

my HTML UI it look like

```
 <div class="row">
                        <label for="f1_normal_input">
                            <strong>Country Code </strong>
                        </label>
                        <div  style="margin-left: 196px;">
                          <input ng-required="true"
                              ng-class="{'error': !!frm.countrycode.$error.isBlank || !!frm.countrycode.$error.invalidLen || !!frm.countrycode.$error.isvalidPattern || !!frm.countrycode.$error.requiredUniquevalue,
                              'valid':!!frm.countrycode.$dirty && !frm.countrycode.$error.isBlank && !frm.countrycode.$error.invalidLen && !frm.countrycode.$error.isvalidPattern  && !!frm.countrycode.$error.requiredUniquevalue}" id="CustomerCode" name="countrycode" ng-model="Country.country_code" type="text"  valid-code />
                                errors : {{frm.countrycode.$error}}
                             <div class="help-inline">
                                <div class="error-icon icon" ng-show="!!frm.countrycode.$error.isBlank" style="right: 5.99998px; top: 33.5px;"></div>
                                <label ng-show="!!frm.countrycode.$error.isBlank" for="v1_normal_input" generated="true" class="error " style="right: -0.000349609px; top: 55px;">This field is required.</label>
                                <label class="error inline" ng-show="!!frm.countrycode.$error.invalidLen">Must be 2-3 characters.</label>
                                <label class="error inline" ng-show="!!frm.countrycode.$error.isvalidPattern">Pattern is not matched exeample(USA)!!</label>
                                <div class="valid-icon icon" ng-show="!!frm.countrycode.$dirty && !frm.countrycode.$error.isBlank && !frm.countrycode.$error.invalidLen && !frm.countrycode.$error.isvalidPattern && !!frm.countrycode.$error.requiredUniquevalue" style="right: 5.99998px; top: 33.5px;"></div>
                                <label class="error inline" ng-show="!!frm.countrycode.$dirty && !frm.countrycode.$error.isBlank && !frm.countrycode.$error.requiredUniquevalue">This country is already exits !!.</label>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>``
```

and my directives look like

```
angular.module('UserValidation', []).directive('validCode', function($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {

                var isBlank = viewValue === '';
                var invalidLen = !isBlank && (viewValue.length < 2 || viewValue.length > 3);
                var isvalidPattern = !isBlank && !invalidLen && !/^[A-Z]{2,3}/.test(viewValue);
                ctrl.$setValidity('isBlank', !isBlank);
                ctrl.$setValidity('invalidLen', !invalidLen);
                ctrl.$setValidity('isvalidPattern', !isvalidPattern);
                $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '/api/BasicData/CountryCode?code=' + viewValue,
                        data: viewValue
                }).success(function(res) {
                    if (res) {

                            ctrl.$setValidity('requiredUniquevalue', true);//exits in database
                        } else {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('requiredUniquevalue', false);// not exits
                        }
                    }).error(function(err) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('requiredUniquevalue', false);
                    });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Is there any problem ??

Comment: Try add return value in your function on `$parsers` like `return true`;

Comment: I try it but still it shows like that.                                                           .errors : {"parse":true,"requiredUniquevalue":true}

Comment: i want it to be like that errors : {}, when i use compile instead of link then it works and submit button enable , but when i use compile it block http method and also block all the validation,

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Dear Stepan, can you give me some example , i tried on it but getting same result..

Comment: can any body give Plunker example using my code..advanced thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment above, you had to return **value** of your validation function.

As [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) say:

> Returning `undefined` from a parser means a parse error occurred. In that case, no `$validators` will run and the `ngModel` will be set to `undefined` unless `ngModelOptions.allowInvalid` is set to true. The parse error is stored in `ngModel.$error.parse`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/rjruj0mn/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = ""
  }).directive('validCode', function($timeout) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {

          var isBlank = viewValue === '';
          var invalidLen = !isBlank && (viewValue.length < 2 || viewValue.length > 3);
          var isvalidPattern = !isBlank && !invalidLen && !/^[A-Z]{2,3}/.test(viewValue);
          ctrl.$setValidity('isBlank', !isBlank);
          ctrl.$setValidity('invalidLen', !invalidLen);
          ctrl.$setValidity('isvalidPattern', !isvalidPattern);
          ctrl.$setValidity('requiredUniquevalue', true);
          //simulate $http call
          if (!isvalidPattern && !invalidLen && !isBlank) {
            $timeout(function() {
              ctrl.$setValidity('requiredUniquevalue', !(viewValue == "AA" || viewValue == "BB"));
            }, 2000);
          }
          return viewValue;
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="testForm">
      <input name="myName" ng-model="name" valid-code>
      <pre>{{testForm.myName.$error}}</pre>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your hard working , can you just help me in this point ..still its shows like that error: {"requiredUniquevalue":true}. i need not this

Comment: i don't need this , how can i remove this .error: {"requiredUniquevalue":true}.

Comment: o_O just remote related code `if (!isvalidPattern && !invalidLen && !isBlank) {
            $timeout(function() {
              ctrl.$setValidity('requiredUniquevalue', !(viewValue == "AA" || viewValue == "BB"));
            }, 2000);
          }`

Comment: thanks again sorry to disturb you . after 2000 seconds this line is back errors : {"requiredUniquevalue":true}. for  this :-  requiredUniquevalue":true , my button is still disable.

Comment: hi Stepan, i need your help..Please help me

Comment: i'm updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/rjruj0mn/). Check it.